# Identify what parts of a function are not covered by unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, code-coverage, visual-studio-2012

In visual studio's code coverage window, it tells me that a function of mine is 89.09% covered.

How can I find the parts of the function that are not covered?

**Note:** I have code coverage coloring selected (though I have no idea what it does).

Using the standard MS testing framework, and this is for a C# solution.

**Update:** [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182496%28VS.110%29.aspx) page seems to say where the options for this are located, but the 5th step (`Under Display items, select the area of code coverage whose display color you want to change. Your choices are Coverage Not Touched Area, Coverage Partially Touched Area, and Coverage Touched Area.`) is not possible as those options are missing.

Comment: Is this in the beta, or the release candidate?

Comment: This is the beta. I was not aware there was an RC, trying that now.

Comment: Was solved by upgrading to the RC. Post as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be worth moving to the RC if you're still on the beta